# Starting threads from another thread inside an object in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

Having a Thread class that when it runs, it starts 2 threads each of witch has its own purpose and they communicate together using a Queue.

One of these threads spawns more threads to process some stuff, I know this might be a bad design but her is my code

```
class MyThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    # stuff
    Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    # some code that start a thread, this one starts fine

    # another thread started here and went fine
    processing_thread = Thread(target=self.process_files())
    processing_thread.daemon = True
    processing_thread.start()
    # more code 

 def process_files(self):
    while True:

      # stuff
      self.publish(file)
      # stuff

 def publish(self, file):
   # more code
   if (condition):
     self.semaphore.acquire(blocking=True)
     # HERE IT BREAKS
     thread = Thread(target=self.process(), args=(satellite, time, )) 
     thread.daemon = True
     thread.start()

 def process(self, satellite, time):
    #interpreter does not reach here
```

I tried staring the thread with:

```
args=(satellite, time,)
args=(satellite, time)
args=(self, satellite, time,)
args=(self, satellite, time)
```

I always get the error message  `TypeError: process() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

What am I missing, or is it even possible to pass arguments this way?

Comment: Try removing the brackets after self.process: thread = Thread(target=self.process, args=(satellite, time, ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment here is correct.

When you are constructing the thread

```
thread = Thread(target=self.process(), args=(satellite, time, ))
```

You are invoking `process`, not passing it as parameter. This means you are trying to pass the result of `process()` to the thread, not the function itself.